# Azure Mobile Apps - An item to insert was not provided

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a new table on my nodeJS custom Azure Mobile App backend. The table is called `readings.js`:

```
var azureMobileApps = require("azure-mobile-apps");
var table = azureMobileApps.table();
table.columns = {
    "text": "string",
    "complete": "boolean"
};
module.exports = table;
```

`app.js`:

```
var express = require("express");
var azureMobileApps = require("azure-mobile-apps");
var app = express();

var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    homePage: true,
    swagger: true
});

mobileApp.tables.import("./tables");

mobileApp.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
    app.use(mobileApp); // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000); // Listen for requests
});
```

and yet, this is the reposnse I get when POST'ing to the API:

[image]

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are developing Azure Mobile Apps on local environment. Here is a [post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-2-local-development/) in the same scenario guiding you how to do. You can refer to detailed info.

Regarding your issue, post data via POSTMAN, please try to select the `raw` radio button in `body` tab, and select the `JSON` content type, then directly write the json object in the textare.
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.